# Windows 10 how to make two identical accounts with shared access to files / programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, user-accounts, user-profiles

I need to know how to make an account that has **access** to **all** my main account's **files** (e.g. Desktop folder), **programs**, and **permissions**. Essentially, I need an extra account that has access to everything on my main account.

Why would I need that? Because I want to be able to use RDP to connect to my computer and access all files / programs while using the computer simultaneously. If I use the same account however, one gets logged off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're proposing to do won't work. Only Server editions of Windows running the RDSH role allow multiple user accounts to log on simultaneously.

However, if you're willing/able to use a different remote access solution that connects to the Windows console session, then you can be logged on the computer at the physical console *and* via a remote connection. As a bonus, creating a separate account would be unnecessary.

One such remote access program is VNC.

Comment: Would the two be able to function independently? i.e. do two different things from both places? I can already log in to two different accounts, it's just that I need access to same file / programs at the same time, and don't want to reinstall them on a different account.

Comment: No. Only the Server editions of Windows permit multiple, simultaneous logon sessions. On top of that, it's a violation of the EULA for two accounts to use a workstation edition of Windows simultaneously.